# Is this UML UseCase Diagram correct

Tags: uml, use-case

http://www.bloodworks.org/Admin/UseCaseS.jpg

Hi i was wondering if this use case diagram is correct.
the User actor becomes a player type Actor.
Or should i just have the other two actors link to the first 3 use cases ?

Comment: can you give more info?  Just a list of the actors and the Use Cases applicable to each would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actors are classifiers.

You can (and should) use ordinary "is-a" inheritance among actors to show the relationships.

Read this:

http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/useCaseDiagram.htm

In particular, look at figure 4.  Student is a generalization of International Student.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should generalize your actors . you should make an arrow with a triangular head from your player type actors to your User actor

Answer (score 0):

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PZ9Y.png)

**ok so would this be better ?**